# Subtracting empty set from another

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am considering two sets $A = \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}\setminus\{\emptyset\}$, $B = \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}\setminus\{\{\emptyset\}\}$. From the definition of the set difference, I have to consider only those elements of the first set that don't belong to the second one. So my guess is $B = \{ \emptyset \}$. $A$ is more problematic - the empty set doesn't have any elements. My guess is there are no elements to remove. Then, is $A = \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$ the correct result?

Comment: Edited to reflect the more common wording you suggested.

Comment: $\{\emptyset\}$ is not the empty set, namely $\emptyset \in \{\emptyset\}$.

Comment: If $A$ had been defined as $\{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\} \setminus \emptyset$ then you would have been correct.

Comment: If coming from a computer science background: `"" != [""]` (use any other convenient false/null/empty value).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are not removing the empty set. You are removing a set whose only element is the empty set, as
$$\emptyset\ne\{\emptyset\}$$

So,
$$A\setminus\{\emptyset\}=\{\{\emptyset\}\}$$

Your claim would be true if the set being removed were indeed empty, i.e.,
$$A\setminus\emptyset=A$$

Comment: Sometimes people identify an object with the singleton containing it. For example, removing *a* from *A* could well mean constructing the set $A\setminus\{a\}$ instead of $A\setminus a$. In this sense the empty set is removed from $A$ when constructing $A\setminus\{\emptyset\}$. This identification (or abuse of language if you will) is confusing in the OP's case, but it can be useful to observe that this identification is sometimes made.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta No, I have used the notation of $A\setminus\{a\}$. And by doing $A\setminus\{\emptyset\}$, you are removing _an element from the set that is the empty set_. By this notation, to get the set difference with the empty set, you would need to specify all element in the empty set in the braces, so maybe $A\setminus\{\}$ could be considered.

Answer (score 13):

Put $\{\varnothing\}=a$ and $\varnothing=b$. Hence, 
$$
A=\{b,a\}\setminus\{b\}=\{a\}=\{\{\varnothing\}\}
$$
$$
B=\{b,a\}\setminus\{a\}=\{b\}=\{\varnothing\}
$$

Comment: Good answer, but I'd suggest changing the first sentence to read "Put $\{\emptyset\}=a$ and $\emptyset=b$ and note that $a\ne b,$" since the identity $\{b,a\}\setminus\{b\}=\{a\}$ depends on $a\ne b.$

Answer (score 6):

It is true that subtracting the empty set gives you back the
set you started with:
$$
A - \emptyset = A.
$$

But $\{ \emptyset \}$ is not the empty set; it has one element, namely,
$\emptyset$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $e:=\varnothing, f:=\{\varnothing\}=\{e\}$.

Then

$$A = \{e, f\}\setminus\{e\}=\{f\}=\{\{\varnothing\}\}\\
B = \{e, f\}\setminus\{f\}=\{e\}=\{\varnothing\}$$

Answer (score 2):

$A = \{\varnothing, \{\varnothing\}\}\setminus\{\varnothing\}$

$B = \{\varnothing, \{\varnothing\}\}\setminus\{\{\varnothing\}\}$

I think that seeing the $\varnothing$ somehow confuses your perception of what is going on. Towards that end, I wonder if this will help.

Let  $x = \varnothing$ and 
$y = \{\varnothing\}$.

Then $A  = \{\varnothing, \{\varnothing\}\}\setminus\{\varnothing\}
     =\{x,y\} \setminus y
     = \{x,y\} \setminus \{x\} = \{y\} = \{\{\varnothing\}\}$

and

$B  = \{\varnothing, \{\varnothing\}\}\setminus\{\{\varnothing\}\} 
    = \{x,y\}\setminus\{y\} = \{x\} = \{\varnothing\}$

---

You could also try this.

$A = \{\varnothing, \{\varnothing\}\}\setminus\{\varnothing\}
   = (\{\varnothing\} \cup \{\{\varnothing\}\})\setminus\{\varnothing\}
   = \{\{\varnothing\}\}$.

$B = \{\varnothing, \{\varnothing\}\}\setminus\{\{\varnothing\}\}
   = (\{\varnothing\} \cup \{\{\varnothing\}\}) \setminus\{\{\varnothing\}\}
   = \{\varnothing\}$

Answer (score 1):

Subtracting empty set means you got the null,But {null } is not the empty set; it has one element.